# Transposing and Merging datasets in R

Tags: r, subset

I am sure there are answers out there to my question but I can't seem to find one that works and im absolutely new to R so apologies for redundancy!

So I have a huge dataset - 17K obs with 35 variables. It was a txt file which I imported and coerced with as.matrix. The 1st column has character values and the rest 34 columns has numeric values.

Structure -

```
>str(data_m)
 chr [1:17933, 1:35] "RAB12" "TRIM52" "C1orf86" "PLAC9" "MORN3" "LOC643783" "LOC389541" "OAZ2" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:35] "Name" "X118" "X12" "X21" ...
```

Now there is another small long form dataset with 2 columns - id and gender.

```
> str(data_maleids)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id    : Factor w/ 34 levels "X118","X12","X21",..: 8 23 9 19 10 7 5 4 2 30 ...
 $ gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...`
```

Eg. -

```
    row.names   id  gender
1   1           X37 male
2   2           X64 male
```

All I want to do is subset the 1st dataset for only those ids ( X37, X64 etc) which are present in the 2nd dataset.

I tried transposing the bigger dataset but that gives me issues in terms of column names and I can't seem to get my way around this.

Comment: When you readin your first dataframe, don't coerce it to a matrix. When you read in your second dataframe (with just id and gender), set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Then, just do `df1[df1$Name %in% df2$id,]`.

Comment: It should be colnames(df1) rather than $Name right ? Because the id in df2 is actually the column names in df1. But the logic worked. Thanks !   However that leads to another step of merging back the 1st column $Name from the original dataset which again works but is not the best way to do it I guess. There should be a way of retaining the column titled Name while subsetting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment is about your statement "The 1st column has character values and the rest 34 columns has numeric values". `data_m` is a matrix, so all columns are of the same type. In this case character. You can see it from the output of the `str()`. Think about a matrix in R as a vector which is arranged in several columns.

Secondly I advise you to use `data.table` package (you have to install it if you do not have it yet) for this task. The sketch of the syntax would be something like this:

1. Read the data in. There is a nice function `fread()` in the
   `data.table` package to read data from text files as a `data.table`
   object: `data_m <- fread("file.name.txt")`
2. Key the `data_m` by variable `id`: `setkey(data_m, id)`
3. Make a vector of ids from the `data_maleids`: `ids <-
   sort(unique(data_maleids$id))`.
4. Select the case you need: `data_m[id
   %in% ids]`.

Comment: Hi.. I tried installing the data.table package but R cant seem to find the fread function ( v 3.0.1)                                                  "Error: could not find function "fread"

Comment: You have to load the package to make it available during a session with `require(data.table)`.